# what type of rendering engine is cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I don't know what type of rendering engine cycles is. is it path tracing ray tracing 
Raydiosidi ray casting photon maping? I would like to know

Comment: Cycles is a Monte Carlo path tracer

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Shouldn't that be an answer, instead of a comment?

Comment: @And jerryno got the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cycles is a ray tracing renderer.
Can use different tracing strategies (under integrator option):

- Path tracing: pure path tracer.
- Branched path tracing: path tracer with branching on the first bounce.

It uses Monte-Carlo for sampling, that means repeated random sampling.

Soon [Metropolis Light Transport](https://developer.blender.org/T38401) should be also available which is a variant to Monte-Carlo, it uses Bidirectional path tracing and Metropolis sampling.